# how to convert Postman request parameters into PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, postman

[image]

I am requesting through potman with the following data 
it's worked(Note: not working like this

tags: [news, sports ])

when I request that endpoint from php with data

```
   $payload = [
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'tags' => ['sports','news']
        ];
```

getting error tags value "'tags' value is not a valid array".

what's alternative to those postman request parameters in PHP

Comment: in postman add like this : 
tags[0]=xyz
tags[1]=abc

and you can get value it in $tags;

Comment: @SachinAghera that api where i am requesting Not accepting 
tags[0] = 12 tags[1] = 1212

Comment: but in image it is post call

Comment: yes its post request'

Comment: [0=>'sports',1=>'news'] use like that

Comment: How are you using `$payload` in your PHP code?